# Sensitivity list error

Tags: verilog, xilinx-ise

I want to compute sum of elements of an array. Elements of the array are assigned on each clock rising edge (sequentially). I don't want to get the sum of elements on the next clock rising edge, So the design of sum must be combinational. I can get the correct result in simulation without any errors, but my code is not synthesized in ISE (Xilinx Synthesis tool). I'm working on Spartan3.

**My code :**

```
always @* begin
    sum = 0;
    for (i=0; i<K; i=i+1)
        sum = sum + shiftReg[i];    
end
```

**ERROR** :

> Xst:902 - Unexpected shiftReg event in always block sensitivity list.

I searched for solutions. [One way](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/20391.html) is to add all of the elements of `shiftReg` in sensitivity list, but in my project the number of elements is `K` (`K` is a parameter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid it's a limitation of the XST synthesizer. The very same solution you provide states that this issue has been solved for Virtex 6 and Spartan 6 devices, so it must be some kind of limitation regarding resources in the Spartan 3, or, more probably, a bit of lazyness from Xilinx engineers.

I've tested this example module:

```
module addall (
  input wire clk,
  input wire [3:0] addr,
  input wire load,
  input wire [7:0] din,
  output reg [7:0] tot
);

  reg [7:0] sr[0:15];
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (load)
      sr[addr] <= din;
  end

  integer i;
  always @* begin
    tot = 8'h00;
    for (i=0;i<=15;i=i+1)
        tot = tot + sr[i];
  end
endmodule
```

It synthesizes well on Icarus Verilog + YOSIS 0.3.0
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/5q9

It synthesizes well in XST 12.4 using a Spartan 6 device

It gives me the same error as you with the same XST version, if I change to Spartan 3E.

Possible workaround: use Icarus Verilog with target `vhdl` to convert the offending module into VHDL and add it to your design instead of the original Verilog module.

Comment: Thank you very much mcleod_ideafix , I tested my code on Spartan6. That error is fixed. I think you're right. Probably it's related to limitations in Spartan3.